# How to test in two paths are hard linkable?

Tags: linux, unix, inode, hardlink

I have file paths in one side and their new paths where I want to duplicate them.

How to test whether they can be simply hardlinked or they should be copied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1: Call [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/link.html).

Step 2: If it returns -1 with `errno` set to `EXDEV`, then make a copy.

[update]

In general, there is no portable (and reliable) way to answer this question.  The closest you can get, I think, is to call [statvfs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstatvfs.html) for the source and destination and then compare the `f_fsid` fields of the [statvfs structures](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_statvfs.h.html).

Unfortunately, POSIX does not guarantee anything in particular about the `f_fsid` field.  This test should work on Linux unless maybe you are asking about NFS-mounted filesystems...

Comment: But it will create hardlink, and I do not want to do this - I need only to know whether it can be done. 

Also I'm talking about shell commands :)

Answer (score 1):

[Nemo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9124325/841108) is indeed the simplest solution: try the `link(2)` syscall.

If you only want to know if the path are hard linkable without even attempting the `link(2)` syscall, you could find their filesystem e.g. using [statfs(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/statfs), check that they are on the same filesystem, and check that the filesystem's type is good enough.